# How should I extend the wiring so I can move a 220v subpanel?

Tags: electrical

I have a 22 subpanel for my hot tub. I have a 220 line that runs about 50 feet to the subpanel and then 5 feet to the hot tub. I need to move the subpanel another 6 feet to the fence. I do I add the length of the 220 line to make it to the fence? Can I just put a junction box in the ground and connect wires together to make it the length I need? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The junction box needs to be accessible, so "in the ground" cannot mean "buried without access."

In many cases it makes more sense to just replace the wire from end-to-end, but if you can put a junction box (that is accessible) either at the former sub-panel location or somewhere closer to the supply (so that you are shortening the supply wires before extending new wire to the new sub-panel location) that should also work.

Comment: When I got a new panel, they just used a subpanel as a junction box. Inspector didn't seem to mind ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Agreed,  with the additional observation that depending on the gauge of your 220V line, a junction box may be less expensive than 60 feet of wire.